# how to stop the touchcarousel once reached the last set of slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using touchcarousel js. I am display 4 columns per slide, I have a total of 14. if I want it to be exact partition, I should only have 12 columns, since I display 4 per slide. my problem now is, once it reached the last set of slide, it keeps sliding when clicking the "right" arrow. I already have this parameters set

```
            pagingNav: false,
            snapToItems: true,
            itemsPerMove: 1,
            scrollToLast: false,
            loopItems: false,
            scrollbar: true,
            itemFallbackWidth:220,
```

it didn't helped at all. How to stop the sliding or disable it once I reached the last set of slides whenever I click the right arrow ?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation

```
    loopItems: false
```

is property you're looking for, description says: Loop items (don't disable arrows on last slide and allow autoplay to loop).

It seems awkwardly worded to. Try set the value to true.

Additionally you can use onAnimComplete callback and hide the arrow on your own when you reach the last slide.

Comment: I've already tried that before asking this in stackoverflow. If I set to true, nothing happen, I can still click the arrow even if I already reach the last set of slide

Comment: see my corrected answer, I think you can make it happen with callback

Comment: do you have an example? like how to know if it already reach the last set of the array ?

Comment: For exapmle you can make your own variable name it whatever you want let's say currentSlide. Initially it'll be set to 1 and whenever you click next button you increase this variable by 1 in this callback and you'll be checking if you're on the last slide, you know how many slides you have right?